# ClassCastException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest cannot be cast GrailsWebRequest

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, grails, tomcat7

I've problem when I deploy 2 same apps on my tomcat. Wars are the same, only app name is diffrent.

Tomcat randomly returns (only for 2nd loaded app):

error 500

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest cannot be
>   cast to org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequest

My BuildConfig

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}.war"

forkConfig = [maxMemory: 1024, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
grails.project.fork = [
   test: forkConfig, // configure settings for the test-app JVM
   run: forkConfig, // configure settings for the run-app JVM
   war: forkConfig, // configure settings for the run-war JVM
   console: forkConfig // configure settings for the Swing console JVM
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins
        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()

        // uncomment these to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        mavenCentral()
        mavenRepo('file:///c:/mvn_repo')
        mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
        mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes eg.

        //runtime 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:sqljdbc4:4.0'
        runtime 'com.microsoft.windowsazure:microsoft-windowsazure-api:0.4.1'
        compile 'commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.1'

        compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.1'
        compile 'com.lowagie:itext:2.1.7'
        compile 'net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports:5.5.0'

    }

    plugins {

        build ":tomcat:7.0.54"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.0.3"
        compile ':cache:1.1.7'

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ':hibernate:3.6.10.10' // or ":hibernate4:4.1.11.BUILD-SNAPSHOT"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.3.3"

        runtime ':resources:1.2.7'

        // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
        runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0.1"
        runtime ":cached-resources:1.1"
        //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

        compile ':spring-security-core:1.2.7.3'
        compile ":cache-headers:1.1.7"
        compile ':jasper:1.6.1'

        compile ':mail:1.0.6'
        compile ":profiler:0.5"
        compile ':smart-sprites-resources:0.3'

    }
}
```

My Config

```
grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:${appName}-config.properties"]
grails.project.groupId = appName // change this to alter the default package name and Maven publishing destination
grails.mime.file.extensions = true // enables the parsing of file extensions from URLs into the request format
grails.mime.use.accept.header = false

grails.mime.types = [ html: ['text/html','application/xhtml+xml'],
    xml: ['text/xml', 'application/xml'],
    text: 'text/plain',
    js: 'text/javascript',
    rss: 'application/rss+xml',
    atom: 'application/atom+xml',
    css: 'text/css',
    csv: 'text/csv',
    all: '*/*',
    json: ['application/json','text/json'],
    form: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    multipartForm: 'multipart/form-data'
]


grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*','/font/*']
grails.resources.adhoc.includes = ['/images/**', '/css/**', '/js/**', '/plugins/**','/font/**']
grails.resources.rewrite.css = false


grails.views.default.codec = "html" // none, html, base64
grails.views.gsp.encoding = "UTF-8"
grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"

grails.views.gsp.sitemesh.preprocess = true

grails.scaffolding.templates.domainSuffix = 'Instance'


grails.json.legacy.builder = false
grails.enable.native2ascii = true
grails.spring.bean.packages = []
grails.web.disable.multipart=false

// request parameters to mask when logging exceptions
grails.exceptionresolver.params.exclude = ['password']

// enable query caching by default
grails.hibernate.cache.queries = true
```

Tested on:

grails version: 2.3.7,2.3.11,2.4.2

tomcat version: 7.0.26,7.0.54

linux and windows

**EDIT:** 2014-07-13 16:00 CEST

Problem occurs only when I used Filter class placed in **Config**/pardus. Last change: asyncAuditService.

```
    package pardus

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

class TermFilters {
    def springSecurityService
    def auditService
    def sessionRegistry

    def asyncAuditService

    def filters = {
        all(controller:'*', action:'*') {

            before = {

                ((HttpServletResponse) response).setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
                log.info "username ${session}"
                log.info "session user ${session.user}"
                log.info "ip address: ${request.getHeader("X-Real-IP")}"
                log.info "all: ${sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals()}"

                def allowAlwaysController = ["login","info","logout"]



                def user = springSecurityService.currentUser

                if(user!=null && !user.enabled && !controllerName.equals('logout')){
                    redirect(controller:'logout');   
                    return false;                 
                }


                if (!springSecurityService.isLoggedIn() && !controllerName.equals('login')){

                    redirect(controller:'login');                    
                    return false;
                }

                if (session.is_confirmed!="true" && !controllerName.equals('info') && !controllerName.equals('login') && !controllerName.equals('logout')){
                    log.info('not confirmed');
                    redirect(controller:'info',action:'term');
                    return false;
                }


                log.info "password o: ${user?.passwordExpired}"
                if(!controllerName.equals('account') && session.is_confirmed=="true" && user!=null && (user.changePasswordReq || user.isMyPasswordExpired()) && !controllerName.equals('info') && !controllerName.equals('login') && !controllerName.equals('logout')){
                    log.info "password o: ${user.passwordExpired}"
                    flash.error = "NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIED"
                    redirect(controller:'account',action:'index');
                    return false;                    
                }

                if(!allowAlwaysController.contains(controllerName)){
                    def role = springSecurityService.currentUser?.getRole()?.authority
                    log.info "controllerName " + controllerName
                    log.info "controllerName " + actionName
                    if(role!=null && (grailsApplication.config.pardus.priv[role][controllerName]==null || !grailsApplication.config.pardus.priv[role][controllerName].contains(actionName))){
                        if(controllerName!="")
                        flash.error = "BRAK_UPRAWNIEN"
                        // todo: loguj incydent bezpieczenstwa
                        log.info "brak uprawnien"
                        redirect(controller:'dashboard',action:'index');
                        return false;                    
                    }

                }

                if(grailsApplication.config.pardus.audit){                  
                    asyncAuditService.audit(params,request.getHeader("X-Real-IP"),session,request.getHeader("user-agent"))
                }


            }
            after = { Map model ->

            }
            afterView = { Exception e ->


            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just rename one of the apps.  They both get placed into the same folder in tomcat, which confuses it.

Comment: Thx Peter, but the apps have got diff names and are in diff folders.

Comment: You'll see a class cast exception like this when you have the same class, loaded from two different class loaders, being casted.  It often happens when you put application libraries into $CATALINA_BASE/lib.  One version of the class is loaded from the common class loader and one is loaded from your web application's class loader.  Try to cast them and you get an exception.  If you put JAR files into $CATALINA_BASE/lib, remove them and bundle them with your WAR file.  If not, maybe attach with a debugger and investigate the two objects before they are cast and compare the class loaders.